# ActionScript 3 SharedObjects

Tags: shared-objects

I have a couple of questions in regards to SharedObjects in as3. Okey, what is the difference between a persistent SharedObject and a nonPersistent SharedObject? And, i am trying to build a small chat application. I want to use the SharedObjects to send messages. Would i be required to use code for both the client side and server-side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am wrong, but shared SharedObjects are similar to javascript cookies, they are stored on user computer, I think you can't use them to send messages

Comment: I think he is talking about remote shared objects here!